# Accessing Python objects in reticulate without `$`

Tags: r, reticulate

The R package `reticulate` has a [custom `$` operator](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/blob/6ee755e2264c2128492b00090731c1717b488f66/R/python.R#L259) which acts as the `.` operator in the equivalent Python modules/objects. Since the second argument of `$` [cannot be evaluated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18228613/7312238), how do you pass an argument to it in this scenario?

The example usage on the `reticulate` README is

```
library(reticulate)
os <- import("os")
os$chdir("tests")
os$getcwd()
```

I'm after the following function where `...` would be the python call with zero or more arguments.

```
my_function <- function(python_object, ...)
```

The `python_object` needs to be of class `python.builtin.object` or `python.builtin.module` and the arguments would need to be passed as characters since the functions don't exist in the global environment.

eg.

```
my_function(os, "chdir", "tests")
my_function(os, "getcwd")
my_function(r_to_py("my_string"), "lstrip", "my_")
```

My thoughts were something along the lines of

```
do.call("chdir", list("tests"), envir = os)
```

or

```
reticulate:::`$.python.builtin.object`(os, eval(parse(text="chdir('tests')")))
```

however neither of these have worked.

Answer (score 2):

Was achieved much simpler than I imagined...

```
my_function <- function(python_module, attribute, ...) {
  py_call(python_module[[attribute]], ...)
}
```

In general, `$` is shorthand for `[[`.

---

**Update**

@jjallaire pointed out...

> py_call is a lower level function which doesn't currently get the
>   benefit of type wrapping (but it certainly should).

To return identical output (ie inherits the correct classes) as `$` use either:

- `do.call(python_module[[attribute]], args = list(function_args))`
- `python_module[[attribute]](function_args)`

instead of `py_call`

See [rstudio/reticulate#149](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/149).