# R Reticulate - Moving defined variables programmatically from Python environment to R

Tags: python, r, iteration, reticulate

**Caue:**

I'm creating dataframes programmatically in Python using `globals()`.

In the below code, I'm creating 5 datasets that starts with a 'PREFIX' in caps, followed by a letter then ending with a suffix.

R

```r
library(reticulate)
repl_python()
```

Python

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

letters = ('a','b','c','d','e')
df_names = []

for ele in letters:
  globals()['PREFIX_{}_suffix'.format(ele)] = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['col_a', 'col_b']).astype(str)
  df_names.append(['PREFIX_{}_suffix'.format(ele)][0])
```

```py
print(df_names)
['PREFIX_a_suffix', 'PREFIX_b_suffix', 'PREFIX_c_suffix', 'PREFIX_d_suffix', 'PREFIX_e_suffix']
```

**Request:**

I would like to select dataframes starting with a prefix (ideally with regular expression `^PREFIX`) and move those specific dataframes from reticulate's python environment to R environment programmatically.

For the sake of the task, I have added the dataframes variable names into `df_names`. However, using regex is highly encouraged.

I know the variables are stored in `py` object that can be accessed with a `$` .. but I'm not sure how to select dataframes iteratively and move those dataframes from python's environment to R's environment programmatically all at once.

---

In R, I usually use `ls(pattern=<regex>)` to select objects in R environment.

In Python, you can list the variables using `locals()`, see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430811/enumerate-or-list-all-variables-in-a-program-of-your-favorite-language-here).

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48373739/accessing-python-objects-in-reticulate-without?rq=1) discuss passing python functions from R to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution using regex:

In python:

- Create your regex pattern to fetch desired defined variables
- Apply your pattern to `dir()` output, which captures the defined variables in your python's environment
- Save selected/fetched variables (dfs) in a list

```py
import os
import re

r = re.compile("^PREFIX")
py_dfs = list(filter(r.match, dir())) # fetch defined variables from python's env
print(py_dfs)
['PREFIX_a_suffix', 'PREFIX_b_suffix', 'PREFIX_c_suffix', 'PREFIX_d_suffix', 'PREFIX_e_suffix']
```

In R:

- Access that list from python that has the selected variables names
- Using R's `reticulate::py_eval` evaluate your python object converting it to r using `reticulate::py_to_r`
- Using `assign` to assign dynamic defined variables with the same `name` of the variables (dataframes) in python

```r
for (df in py$py_dfs){
  name  = df
  r_df = py_to_r(py_eval(df))
  assign(paste0(name), r_df)
}

> ls(pattern="^PREFIX")
[1] "PREFIX_a_suffix" "PREFIX_b_suffix" "PREFIX_c_suffix" "PREFIX_d_suffix" "PREFIX_e_suffix"
> dim(PREFIX_a_suffix)
[1] 0 2
> class(PREFIX_a_suffix)
[1] "data.frame"
>
```